# Stopping an intent service which is doing a timertask in android

Tags: android, android-intent, intentservice

I am using intent service to periodically send queries to my server to check if there are any updates. In the intent service there is a timer task, which queries the server every 3 seconds, This starts running when the application is closed.
Now when the user again comes back in to the application I want to stop the service.
How should I do this?  how can an intent service which is doing  timertask be stopped form another activity?
Please give suggestions for Intent Service because that is what I am using.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it will be better to use just service instead of IntentService.

```
public class UpdateService extends Service {

   public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        public void startUpdates() {
           // start updateThread if it not started, or
           // notify about resuming probes
        }

        public void stopUpdates() {
           // make updateThread to wait, until startUpdates
           // called again.
           // 
           // REMEMBER this method can be called when startUpdates didnt called.
        }
   }

   // For simplicity we will use local binder.
   private final IBinder binder = new LocalBinder();

   @Override
   public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
       return binder;
   }

   private Thread updateThread = new Thread() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
        while (true) {
            // Do updates. Sleep/awake managment.
        }
       }
   };
}
```

Just [bind](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#bindService%28android.content.Intent,%20android.content.ServiceConnection,%20int%29) to service (with [AUTO_CREATE_FLAG](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#BIND_AUTO_CREATE)) and start updates when you are need.
When your activity shows just bind again to service and make it stop updates.

Answer (score 0):

First of all,IntentService cannot be stopped.It will stop itself only after it has completed all the tasks present in its queue.Hence,IntentService should not be used here.